# How do I create a box that explains input fields as a user progresses through a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like a box very much like the one on the Ask Question page which explains/clarifies what kind of data should go into each field of a form. I have tried to "view source" on this page but I simply can't make heads nor tails of what's going on. Could someone please explain it or is there a tutorial I could use?

Example:

1. When a user clicks into a text input the box explains what should go there
2. Drop-down menu labeled Company Type with several types of companies. Users have been misclassifying themselves because they don't understand what each type refers to. When the user clicks on the drop-down menu, the text within the box explains each company type.

See link for screenshot of a part of the form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAGRl.jpg

I would also like to have the box travel down the form (so that it is always just to the right of the field that the user is working with)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a sample of the form? If users are inputting incorrect information, I imagine all that needs to happen is the labels need to be made more clear?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of a section of the form. Off to the right of the actual form I'd like a box which explains each field (probably onFocus) like the div that explains each field on the Ask Question page

http://imgur.com/TYOmT

Answer (score 0):

Given HTML like so:

```
    <form>
        <select name="some_name" id="some_name">
            <option value="option1" data-description="Description of option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2" data-description="Description of option2">option2</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="description">
        Default Description
    </div>​
```

the following javascript will take the value of `data-description` of the selected option, and populate the `#description` with it.

```
    var $description = $('#description');
    $('#some_name').on('change', function(event){
        var $option = $(event.currentTarget).find(':selected');
        $('#description').html($option.attr('data-description'));
    });
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bfSkn/).

You can easily extend that to create something to give more information for each particular input by either creating additional handlers for each input, or for creating a handler for any input on the form.

There are a variety of different ways you can keep the description fixed, using `display:fixed` or something like Twitter Bootstrap's [affix](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix).